# Warning message identifier

Tags: matlab, warnings

I would like to include the `warning()` command in my MATLAB code. Ironically, in doing so, I get a warning message in the code editor that I'm unable to shift.

If I use the line `warning('Warning message!')`, the code editor tells me I need to include a 'message identifier' as the first argument. So, I consulted `help warning`, which informs me that 'message identifier' is simply a string.

If I use the following line:
`warning('identifier','Warning message!')`, I *still* get complaints from the editor. First of all, it still wants me to add a 'message identifier' as the first argument. In addition, it now tells me that 'the format string might not agree with the argument count'.

How do I resolve this?

I'm using MATLAB 2012a.

Comment: This should work ok. What is the ironic warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
warning('myfun:warncode','Warning message!')
```

Comment: Yep. And this is right out of the `help` for `warning`: "A message identifier is a string of the form <component>[:<component>]:<mnemonic>, where <component> and <mnemonic> are alphanumeric strings (for example, 'MATLAB:singularMatrix')". Always read the help when you have an issue -completely.